# Oracle Express 11g - hired after another employee's hired date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an `EMPLOYEES` table that needs to display `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `EMPLOYEE_NAME`, `HIREDATE` for employees who have been hired after Jack was hired. I have the follow syntax and the syntax error shows:

> SQL command not properly ended.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIREDATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIREDATE > EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'JACK';
```

I tried with () around the `JACK` also, and still not working.

Answer (score 3):

You first have to find out when Jack was hired:

```
SELECT HIREDATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'JACK';
```

You can then use it as a subquery for your `WHERE` condition. This is the finished query:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, HIREDATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIREDATE > (
  SELECT HIREDATE
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'JACK'
);
```